# How do I write a Drupal 8 modal button

Tags: 8, javascript

So I'm trying to open a modal via a button in Drupal 8 beta 11. I've patterned my code after some I found in BlockListBuilder.php in core, but I can't seem to get it to work. My routes are correct because I've successfully made a modal link. Here's my code:

```
$row['button'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => $this->t('Modal'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
      '#url' => Url::fromRoute('settings_profile'),
      '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('use-ajax'),
        'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
        'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode(array(
          'width' => 500,
          'height' => 500,
        )),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Does it work now with the typo corrected?

Comment: No, I haven't gotten it to work. If I change it over to a link type, it works. I wonder if buttons just aren't wired for the new data-dialog-type => 'modal' stuff yet.

Comment: I searched for the correct method to open a dialog and finally stumbled upon this: https://www.drupal.org/node/1989646 I found the correct approach to my issue, hope it helps!